# displaing received layout file from server to user in runtime android

Tags: android, layout, xml-parsing, layout-inflater

I want display received layout file from server to user.after googling I find out I cant place my file in raw/asset folder and can't use android's LayoutInflater for inflat my file .one existing way is use Defaulthandler and processing it for creating views and viewgroups.please help me with represent other ways that I can use for this problem with example.thanks

Comment: Get the information about layout from server and create it on Runtime.

Comment: please more explain  @Brontok

Comment: my layout file can be very complex right same a layout in layout folder @Brontok

Comment: Get the information like orientation, no. of buttons,no. of images etc from server and create the UI at runtime.

Comment: Why are you not creating it in layout folder?

Comment: I want can display from server to user any layout. @Brontok

Comment: Ok even if you do, What about click listeners for view objects? How will your set id's to them?